# replace both http and http: from url

Tags: php, regex

```
Tried this,

$url = preg_replace('!(http|http:|ftp|scp)(s)?:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9.=?&-_/]+!', "<a style=text-decoration:underline;color:blue href=\"\\0\" target='_blank' >\\0</a>",$feed->feed_text)):
```

I want to replace both http and http: from the url. I tried the above one which is replacing the `http` and not `http:`.But if i tried any one of then in regex it is working.If i use both in the expression it is not replacing the `http:`

Please see the embeded script i am using,

1.`<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="chat_embed" src="http://twitch.tv/chat/embed?channel=athenelive&popout_chat=true" height="500" width="350"></iframe>` ->having http:(need to remove)

2.`<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/JxHOjZLRxAg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>` ->if i use http: alone in regex this youtube embedded script is not taken as youtube url. For both compatible purpose i used `http|http:`.

Update:

I need to remove http: from the 1st frame given above.

Should look line

```
<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="chat_embed" src="//twitch.tv/chat/embed?channel=athenelive&popout_chat=true" height="500" width="350"></iframe>
```

Comment: Your `preg_replace` replaces urls with urls embedded in `a` tags... how do you get to an iframe from that?

Comment: @Robin I tried hardcoded the value with removed http: i am getting the frame

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what that means. Your code in the `preg_replace` is (should be) replacing `http://sth.org` with `<a ...>http://sth.org</a>`. What's the link with an iframe?

Comment: Please give an example of input and desired output.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work for `http:` because you put a colon after the capturing group:

```
(http|http:|ftp|scp)(s)?:
          ^             ^
```

To solve the problem, remove the `http:` from the capturing group (that is useless):

```
(http|ftp|scp)(s)?:
```

I think your are looking for that:

```
$url = preg_replace('~\bhttps?:~', '', $url);
```

Comment: initially i tried your solution but that too not escaping the http: -->preg_replace('!(http|ftp|scp)(s)?:\/\/[a-zA-Z

Comment: Can you tell me how to replace http: in this expression this is to save the embeded script in db ->preg_match('/<iframe.*src=\"(.*)\".*/isU', $_POST['embed_url'], $embed_string);

Comment: @user2439275: But what are you trying to do? Your goal seems more and more obscure. Are you trying to find all the iframe in an html code and then store these whole iframe tags to db after removing `http:` from the src attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `(http|http:)` with

```
http:?
```

When in an alternation, the regex engine tries the matches in order. In `http://sthg.com`, `http` matches so it has no reason to try the `http:` variant. (using `(http:|http)` would actually work for you)

Using the greedy `:?` will solve the issue.

Also, to improve your regex, the parenthesis around `(s)?` are useless (`s?` is enough) and `/` is not a special character if you don't use it as a regex delimiter (here you're using `!`) so no need to escape them.

Comment: tried this preg_replace('!(http:?|ftp|scp)(s)?:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9.=?&-_/]  ->not working

Answer (score 0):

If you want to strip http:// just do the following :

```
$url = str_replace('http:', '', $my_url);
```

Comment: Updated. Straightest solution, why use a complicated regular expression, when you already know you don't need a precise sequence of character ?

Comment: ... because it does need a precise sequence of characters ... either `http` or `http:` (or, looking at the question also `ftp` or `scp` - potentially with the implication that there may or may not be colons there as well) - granted you're never going to get an URL that starts `http//` (without the colon) :)

Comment: Oh ... realistically it's also got to be only at the start of the string as well so that you don't break URLs like `http://www.fred.com/http:/lovelyhttp:code.html` - with `str_replace` you'd need to provide the `count` parameter `str_replace('http:', '', $feed->feed_text, 1)` which is fine unless the URL happens to be `//www.fred.com/http:/lovelyhttp:code.html` in the first instance ... in which case you're going to break the URL again.

Comment: Looking at the request the OP asks for "http" to be replaced (he probably took the regular expression from somewhere and copy-pasted it). I assumed he's only going to take service-generated urls to embed players, so I omitted the count parameter (though it was needed in such case), by the way +1 for the second case, I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the question - you might be better off just removing everything before the initial '//' - it looks as though you want the URLs to appear as *//www.somewhere.com/something/something/darkside/something/* - so using a RegExp like this might suit your purposes better:

```
$url = preg_replace('|^[^/]*(//.*)$|', "$1", $feed->feed_text);
```